# Why is this BeautifulSoup code outputting "None"?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

contenturl = "http://espnfc.com/tables/_/league/esp.1/spanish-la-liga?cc=5901"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(contenturl).read())

table = soup.find('div id', attrs={'class': 'content'})

rows = soup.findAll('tr')
for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td')
    for td in cols:
        text = td.find(text=True)
        print text,  
    print
```

and I get: (note this is only a little bit of what I was looking for, which are standings for a soccer league)

```
&nbsp; Overall None Home None Away None &nbsp;
POS None TEAM P W D L F A None W D L F A None W D L F A None GD Pts
1 
Barcelona 38 32 4 2 115 40 None 18 1 0 63 15 None 14 3
```

My question is, 
Why is there a "None" after every word? Is there a way I can make it stop doing that?

Answer (score 1):

If you notice on the website, there are spaces between some info, and this is included in each td.

You may notice that all the spaces have a width. So, you can do this:

```
cols = tr.findAll('td', width=None)
```

If you decide to swap to BeautifulSoup 4 at any stage, use:

```
cols = tr.findAll('td', width=False)
```

Comment: that just prints a bunch of empty lines

Comment: For this to work with BeutifulSoup 3, then use `cols = tr.findAll('td', width=None)`

Answer (score 0):

The None happen when an element has multiple children like it says in [The Docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#string)

the easiest way to get rid of the`None` is like this:

```
for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td')
    for td in cols:
        text = td.find(text=True)
        if text is not None:
            print text,  
    print
```

that will check if `text = None` and if it is it wont print it

Comment: From [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations): `Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or is not, never the equality operators.`